# Text input is using original typed text instead of selected google place autocomplete text

Tags: html, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, textbox

I'm using the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 to autocomplete a text input in my angular/node app.

The problem I'm running into is that for some reason, my angular function is using the original typed text instead of the selected google place autocomplete text that gets filled into the text input.

Here is what happens (in pictures!):

**1) Type in the beginning of the place I'm looking for**
[image]

**2) click on the autocomplete place, which fills the text input**
[image]

**3) The string used in my get calls to Google Places API is the original "siz" from step one instead of the place info from autocomplete, which returns the wrong place**
[image]

Here is the code that I think is relevant to this problem:

From main.html:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<div class="input-group">
  <input ng-model="businessName" googleplace class="form-control input-lg">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button ng-click="findGPlace2()" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Find!</button>
  </span>
</div><!-- /input-group -->
```

From Google.js controller (the `console.log($scope.businessName);` is printing out `siz` in this example):

```
$scope.findGPlace2 = function() {
  console.log($scope.businessName);
  GoogleService.findPlace2($scope.businessName).then(function(data) {
    $scope.gPlace2 = data;
    // for(var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
    //   console.log(data.results[i]);
    // }
    showGData(data.results[0].place_id);
  });
};
```

From App.js (custom autocomplete directive):

```
  analyticsApp.directive('googleplace', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, model) {
      var options = {
        types: [],
        componentRestrictions: {}
      };
        scope.gAuto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], options);

        google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function() {
          scope.$apply(function() {
          model.$setViewValue(element.val());                
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be something wrong with your `googleplace` directive.
Check [this fiddile](http://jsfiddle.net/mwDQr/1/). It might help you

```
 scope.gAuto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], options);
```

This should be

```
 scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], options);
```

I think that should do it.

Comment: That is exactly what I modelled my directive off of. See my updated question which includes the directive.

Comment: @novicePrgrmr Check the edit. I think I have spotted the error